# Image not showing for Altair mark_image url

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to reproduce this example with my own images but the images don't show. I replaced the third image in the example with my own image that I uploaded to github in a public repository. I had previously tried with images in a google cloud storage bucket, which didn't work either. I also replaced the second image with a link to a stock image and that one works. What am I missing?

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
      {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.5, "img": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/ffox.png"},
      {"x": 1.5, "y": 1.5, "img": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/sunflower-isolated-picture-id174648035"},
      {"x": 2.5, "y": 2.5, "img": "https://github.com/flbyrne/images/blob/main/snowman.png"}
])

alt.Chart(source).mark_image(
    width=50,
    height=50
).encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    url='img'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the raw GitHub link (right click the image and open it in a new tab):

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flbyrne/images/main/snowman.png
```

instead of

```
https://github.com/flbyrne/images/blob/main/snowman.png
```